# Print each element on a new line in a list of a lists + using delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a program where I have a txt file as an input which contains several rows similar to this but with different values:

> MOD/ABC//BF/56/290/BB/0//////

> DAM/DEF//BF/25/450/BB/0//////

My program is below where I'm able to print each row, able to print each row through indices, however I'm having trouble with defining a function where I can take that list of rows, delimit out the "/" and then use that cleaned data to calculate quantities.

My ideal output would be to use the cleaned data to quantify how much "MOD" or "DAM" there are with the same lines if they contain the same variables like "BF" or "BB".

Output like this:

> MOD, ABC, BF, BB - x45

> MOD, ABC, WF - x5

> DAM, DEF, BF, BB - x12

Any pointers appreciated! My output from my function is that it does split each object from the txt file and eliminates the "/" but it prints each row onto one long line.

How can I split those onto new lines?

```
a = "tring.txt" #This can be changed to a = input("Enter filename: ", )
file1 = open(a, "r")
with open(a) as file:
  lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
  print(*lines, sep = "\n")
print("\n")
print(f'Searchable by index: {lines[0]}')
print("\n")
#Defines the function to split the elements.
b = file1.read()
def split_lines(b, delimiter):
  split_txt = b.split(delimiter)
  cleaned_split_txt = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in split_txt]
  print(cleaned_split_txt, sep = "\n")

split_lines(b, '/')

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've already read the file in to variable `lines`. You can just pass those lines into whatever function you want to use to parse them. Then loop over each line, and parse it however you need.

Something like the following.

```
def split_lines(lines, delimiter):
    for line in lines:
        tokens = line.split(delimiter)
        print(tokens)

split_lines(lines, '/')
```

Comment: This worked beautifully - appreciate your time!